Trying to identify a European film from 1970s or 1980s
After nearly 30 years, it is driving me crazy trying to identify a European film I saw on TV in very late 1980s or v. early 1990s.
Ot was on late at night, I believe on Channel 4 as part of a series of European films. 
I think it may have been French or Spanish. Two scenes stand out vividly:
Man is on the run. 
Black helicopter swoops over valley and town looking for him. 
He hides by houses and looks up as helicopter swoops over. 
At the end of the film, he has climbed a mountain range (Pyrenees?) and is about to escape over the frontier. Then, a line of soldiers appears from behind a ridge and thwarts his escape at the last moment.
That's all I can remember, but it would be brilliant if someone recognises the film and can give me more information. 
Thank you. 

It is "Figures in a Landscape" (1970).
IMDb:

Two escapees are on the run in the wilderness of an unspecified
  country. Wherever they go, they are followed by a menacing black
  helicopter.

I know this movie very well, I am 100% sure this is the one you are looking for. It ends as you described. Robert Shaw and a young Malcolm McDowell are the two escapees who are relentlessly pursued. In the trailer below you can see the menacing black helicopter.
Here is a trailer:



You can watch the movie here, unfortunately in crap quality:



Menacing black helicopter pursuing Robert Shaw:


You are a star! Thank you so much.

You are welcome. Please mark my answer above as the correct answer using the checkmark. Many thanks and enjoy the movie.
